# MongoDB find vs aggregate performance

Tags: mongodb, mongodb-query, aggregation-framework

I am trying to measure MongoDB's find vs aggregate performance.
is there any way to compare aggregate with match and find query performance.

currently I am using JavaScript to measure it.
as `find()`:

```
var start = (new Date).getTime();
db.assets.find({
  "catalog_id":"f1a7669654584a42958d9589cf37d173",
  "albums":{"$elemMatch":{"id":"5f7938ce6e2718eb776f82474f2e093f","order":{"$exists":false}}}
});
var end = (new Date).getTime();
print("elapsed " + (end - start) +" msec");
```

as `aggregate()`:

```
var start = (new Date).getTime();
db.assets.aggregate([
  {
    "$match":{
      "catalog_id":"f1a7669654584a42958d9589cf37d173",
      "albums":{"$elemMatch":{"id":"5f7938ce6e2718eb776f82474f2e093f","order":{"$exists":false}}}
    }
  }
]);
var end = (new Date).getTime();
print("elapsed " + (end - start) +" msec");
```

but it doesn't seems right to me.
Can someone suggest some other way to do it.

Comment: theres no difference between `find()` and `aggregate()` when the aggregation pipeline only contains a **`$match`** stage. Take a look at the `explain()` of thoses queries to better understant what's happening here

Comment: I have tried with explain. but it doesn't give execution time in case of aggregate. Wanted to measure the time taken by both the queries.

Answer (score 0):

The  [`db.collection.explain()`](https://docs.mongodb.com/manual/reference/method/db.collection.explain/#db.collection.explain)  operations can return information regarding:

- [queryPlanner](https://docs.mongodb.com/manual/reference/explain-results/#queryplanner), which details the plan selected by the [query optimizer](https://docs.mongodb.com/manual/core/query-plans/) and lists the rejected plans;
- [executionStats](https://docs.mongodb.com/manual/reference/explain-results/#executionstats), which details the execution of the winning plan and the rejected plans; and
- [serverInfo](https://docs.mongodb.com/manual/reference/explain-results/#serverinfo), which provides information on the MongoDB instance.

How to explain in [find()](https://docs.mongodb.com/manual/reference/method/db.collection.explain/#explain-find-with-modifiers)?

```
db.assets.explain("executionStats").find({
  "catalog_id":"f1a7669654584a42958d9589cf37d173",
  "albums":{"$elemMatch":{"id":"5f7938ce6e2718eb776f82474f2e093f","order":{"$exists":false}}}
});
```

How to explain in [aggregate()](https://docs.mongodb.com/manual/reference/method/db.collection.aggregate/#return-information-on-aggregation-pipeline-operation)?

```
db.assets.explain("executionStats").aggregate([
  {
    "$match":{
      "catalog_id":"f1a7669654584a42958d9589cf37d173",
      "albums":{"$elemMatch":{"id":"5f7938ce6e2718eb776f82474f2e093f","order":{"$exists":false}}}
    }
  }
]);
```